# Step/Debug Android built-in applications

Tags: java, android

I have downloaded the Android source code and can see the java source files for the built-in applications (e.g. com.android.contacts.ContactsListActivity).  I am trying to discover how these applications re-use one another via Intents etc.  I would also like to see how the UI layouts are assembled for these applications as a design for my own apps.

Answer (score 2):

About using Intents and Intent Filters, if you are less experienced, it will be best for you, if you start learning from a book, then try something in your own application, and only after that dive in the pre-installed apps, IMHO.

You can debug built-in applications, just like any other application, if you have the source. If you want to install other version of a built-in app, you must use the appropriate Intent Filters and change the package name, so that it's different than the original application's.

If you are using the source code, browsing through the internal classes should be helpful, so take a look [here](http://stuffthathappens.com/blog/2008/11/01/browsing-android-source-in-eclipse/).

If you want to examine the UI layout of the built-in apps, the **hierarchyviewer** in your Android */tools/* folder is your best choice (my second favorite of the bunch, after **traceview**).

Write back, if something is unclear or doesn't work for you.

Good luck.

Comment: Just to add. You can use LogCat to follow Intent calls in Android source code.